# SQL - Display the minimum value of an average price

Tags: sql, average, min

My database contains a list of products and finishes.  I have been able to successfully average the price of each finish option, but I only want to display the lowest priced option.

Here is a sample of my data.

Table 1 - product_t

```
ProductID   ProductLineID   ProductDescription  ProductFinish   ProductStandardPrice    ProductOnHand
1   1   "Cherry End Table"  Cherry  175.00  0
2   1   "Birch Coffee Tables"   Birch   200.00  0
3   1   "Oak Computer Desk" Oak 750.00  0
4   1   "Entertainment Center"  Cherry  1650.00 0
```

This query results in a list of each available product finish and the average price of an item that has the finish.

```
SELECT ProductFinish, AVG(ProductStandardPrice) as AveragePrice
FROM product_t
WHERE ProductFinish IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ProductFinish;
```

However, I only want to display the lowest price that results from this query.  I attempted this query, but it will not execute.

```
 SELECT ProductFinish, MIN (AVG(ProductStandardPrice)) as AveragePrice
 FROM product_t
 WHERE ProductFinish IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY ProductFinish;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.  It is much appreciated.

Comment: please tag the dbms being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical way to get the lowest value is to use `order by` and some sort of limit on the number of rows.  In ANSI standard SQL, this would be:

```
SELECT ProductFinish, AVG(ProductStandardPrice) as AveragePrice
FROM product_t
WHERE ProductFinish IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ProductFinish;
ORDER BY AveragePrice ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note that some databases using `LIMIT 1` or `TOP 1` instead of `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`.  Also, this version only fetches one record with the lowest price.  If there are duplicate minimums, an arbitrary value is chosen.